# Xamarin using Android.Support.V7.Widget and RecyclerView Error

Tags: android, xamarin

[image]

I have a problem with RecyclerView and **Android.Support.V7** in Xamarin..
Like you can see in the photo, there is an errors.
I added **AppCompat**. I try to delete from **Local\Xamarin** all **Android.Support.*** folders,after this i close VS and clean solution and then rebuild. but still i get errors!
What can i do?
I try almost anything i saw here and nothing help me.

Comment: try to install appcompat via nuget ?

Comment: @EAKTEAM I install, right click on Components and Get more..

Comment: try to install via nuget package manager console : `Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat -Version 25.1.1`

Comment: @EAKTEAM I need to delete all support folders before?

Comment: unisstall support library before from xamarin components , and delete manyally , after this make an installation via nuget

Comment: @EAKTEAM Still same problem

Comment: could you please provide your full code ?

Comment: @EAKTEAM What part of the code you need?

Comment: your activity or fragment where you are using support library

Comment: @EAKTEAM This is the first place i use it

Comment: @EAKTEAM Right after i install, i try this lines code and get my errors

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: Do you see support references in referentre tree into solution explorer ?

Comment: @EAKTEAM Yes, 8 support(s)

Comment: hmmmm... its weird , try to create new project , add thoose library via nuget again and see if something different ?

Comment: Have you install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.V7.RecyclerView` package?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Yes...